# Erase parts of image or overlay with different color

Tags: image-processing

Is there a way of erasing part of an image? I have been looking for a tool that would enable me to do this. Is there one?

Here is a simple minimum working example. I make an image that has some unwanted black dots that I would like to erase.

```
pts1 = RandomReal[{1, 1.2}, {500, 2}];
pts2 = RandomReal[{-0.5, -0.57}, {500, 2}];
g = Graphics[{Point[pts1], Point[pts2], Red, Thickness[0.02], 
    Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}];
gr = Rasterize[g, ImageResolution -> 100];
gr
```

[image]

Now I can use the mask tool to identify the areas I wish to remove

[image]

I have drawn around the unwanted points and can copy this mask as graphics.

[image]

I then change the color of the mask and overlay it onto my original image.

```
ImageCompose[gr, {Graphics[{GrayLevel[1], mask[[1, 2]]}]}]
```

[image]

This is beginning to work but I have got the alignment wrong and my mask does not correctly overlay the unwanted points.

I think this could be made to work by using correct image-processing procedures which for me are new. Also, an even better approach would be to have a `DynanamicModule` where you could use the mouse to erase or to overlay a selected color onto unwanted parts of the image.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I think the Drawing Tools palette should suffice. If you hit Control-D or go to Graphics->Drawing tools, you should be able to find what you're looking for there. There's also a largish docs page about them: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette

Comment: @CarlLange Thanks,  Yes you can use Drawing Tools but it takes many clicks to just cover up one region with a circle.  I would really like to just sweep the mouse around and erase as it moves.  However, if you  don't have many points to erase than Drawing Tools is probably the way to go.